# Need a common way to write an array for Windows 8 Store, Iphone, and Android

Tags: java, android, iphone, arrays, windows-8

I am currently writing an app that takes data and presents it to the user in a type of Q and A study program. First app that I am writing so outside of my normal basic C++ shell on this. Currently developing the windows 8 version in C# but I don't want to have to answer 4000 entries with multiple data points for each question later on. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

tl;dr A way to use a common data set that is transferable between android, Iphone, and Windows 8 store apps.

Comment: What about a Sqlite database? or just an XML/JSON/Text file?

Answer (score 1):

If these are constant data you can present them as an XML file

```
<questions>
<question id="1" text="Your favorite artist">
<answer id="1" text="Picasso"/>
<answer id="2" text="Rafael"/>
<answer id="3" text="Don't know any"/>
</question>
</questions>
```

All those platforms have XML parsers.

Answers can be stored as an SQL database with 1 table: fields: Question id and Answer id.

Comment: Some of the data will be constant, such as the questions that I don't want to re-input 4000 times over but the statistics on how often they get each question right will have to vary. Any idea on this or links to helpful sites?

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to store the data on the device or have it available in the cloud?  The latter approach provides much more flexibility for you, you can modify the data at any time - adding information, making corrections, etc. - and that same data set would be available through services to all of your disparate clients.

You might take a look at [Window Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) (or other Background-as-a-Service offering) to provide that storage and service endpoint.  WAMS fronts a SQL database, but provides SDKs for all the mobile platforms to easily access the data.  There's also a free tier and you can [try anything on Azure out for 90-days](http://aka.ms/GetAzureTrial) with no charge or commitment.

For offline capabilities, you could still leverage Mobile Services via background tasks to make sure some subset of your question bank is available on device and then sync later when you are on-line.  It's a bit more work to provide that type of implementation, but it makes for a much richer experience for the user.

Comment: I want to make it is an offline database, it's an MCAT study program. I am just wondering what way to program the database of questions I should use since I have very little experience outside of C++ and absolutely none with translating programs. I am just going to re-write the program in the other languages and just plug the hard part (database) into the shell program. This is why the database has to be independent of the program if you get what I am saying.

Comment: ok, then I'd probably just go with a flat JSON file storing the data, since your schema isn't too complex and the amount of data you're writing (score, missed values, etc.) doesn't seem too heavy either.  If you want/need to pull in relational semantics then as someone else mentioned SQLite would be a good choice as it has support on all those platforms.